# I keep getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: imgArray is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have written some code as an object to fade in and out some images, only when I call for the slideshow to be build, I am getting an

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: imgArray is not defined".

Can anyone help as to why I am getting this error.  Thank you.

```
const slideShow = {
  curIndex: 0,
  imgDuration: 10000,
  slider: document.querySelector('.banner__slider').childNodes,

  imgArray: [
    'images/background/img3.jpg',
    'images/background/img1.jpg',
    'images/background/img2.jpg'
  ],

  buildSlideShow(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = arr[i];
      slider.appendChild(img);
    }
  },

  slideShow() {

    function fadeIn(e) {
      e.className = "fadeIn";
    };

    function fadeOut(e) {
      e.className = "";
    };

    fadeOut(slider[curIndex]);
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex === slider.length) {
      curIndex = 0;
    }

    fadeIn(slider[curIndex]);

    setTimeout(function () {
      slideShow();
    }, imgDuration);
  },
}; 

slideShow.buildSlideShow(imgArray).slideShow();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because there is no `imgArray` variable in the code. You could change this to:

```
slideShow.buildSlideShow(slideShow.imgArray).slideShow();
```

This fixes one issue but creates another one. The `buildSlideShow` method doesn't return anything. So, `.slideShow()` method will again throw an error. Since, `imgArray` is a property of `slideShow` object, you can make use of the **[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** keyword. Change the method to:

```
buildSlideShow() {

  for (i = 0; i < this.imgArray.length; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.imgArray[i];
    slider.appendChild(img);
  }

  return this;
}
```

From the `buildSlideShow`, return the instance of the object by using `return this`. This way you can chain the methods.

```js
const slideShow = {
  curIndex: 0,
  imgDuration: 10000,
  // slider: document.querySelector('.banner__slider').childNodes,

  imgArray: [
    'images/background/img3.jpg',
    'images/background/img1.jpg',
    'images/background/img2.jpg'
  ],

  buildSlideShow() {
    console.log("inside buildSlideShow method");
    
    for (i = 0; i < this.imgArray.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.imgArray[i]);
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.imgArray[i];
      //slider.appendChild(img);
    }
    
    return this;
  },
  
  slideShow() {
    console.log("inside slideShow method")
  }
}

slideShow.buildSlideShow()
         .slideShow();
```

(I have commented out the `slider` code)

Answer (score 0):

`imgArray` is not a global variable its property of the Object `slideShow`. You should pass `slideShow.imgArray` to the function

```
slideShow.buildSlideShow(slideShow.imgArray).slideShow();
```

And also fix the type missing `b` in start of `uildSlideShow(arr){...}`. It should be `buildSlideShow(arr){...}`